# Spinner with transparent background?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a spinner with a white background which is animated through a keyframe. So, having this code pen, how could I remove this color to "smt-spinner-inner-circle" class without affecting the original desing? If the background is removed, the portion is visible. I have tried to apply a clip but the result is not the expected.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpagJN

Html:

```
<div class="smt-spinner-circle">
   <div class="smt-spinner"></div>
   <div class="smt-spinner-inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```

To sum up, I need the background of the spinner transparent, not red, since the website will be different backgrounds depending on the page you are (grey, white, etc)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not do like this, which will be transparent on top of any backgrounds, images included

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.test.red{
  background: red;
}
.test.green{
  background: green;
}
.test.image{
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/200/nature/1/);
}

.smt-spinner-circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.smt-spinner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  animation: rotate--spinner 1.6s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate--spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test red">
  <div class="smt-spinner-circle">
   <div class="smt-spinner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test green">
  <div class="smt-spinner-circle">
   <div class="smt-spinner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test image">
  <div class="smt-spinner-circle">
   <div class="smt-spinner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Your `background-color` hides triangle that rotates, so simply change `background: white` to match your background color.

```css
body{
  background: red;
}
.smt-spinner-circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.smt-spinner-inner-circle {
  width: 92%;
  height: 92%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.smt-spinner {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: 25px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  animation: rotate--spinner 1.6s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate--spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="smt-spinner-circle">
   <div class="smt-spinner"></div>
   <div class="smt-spinner-inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly, I need the background of the spinner transparent, not red, since the website will be different backgrounds depending on the page you are (grey, white, etc)..

Comment: @Antonio Than you need to create transparent image and rotate it or create transparent GIF

Answer (score 1):

CSS Code

```css
@keyframes ldio-rpinwye8j0b {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) }
  50% { transform: rotate(180deg) }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
.ldio-rpinwye8j0b div {
  position: absolute;
  animation: ldio-rpinwye8j0b 1s linear infinite;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 #e15b64;
  transform-origin: 80px 82px;
}
.loadingio-eclipse {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ldio-rpinwye8j0b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: 0 0; /* see note above */
}
.ldio-rpinwye8j0b div { box-sizing: content-box; }
```

```html
<div
class="loadingio-eclipse">
  <div class="ldio-rpinwye8j0b">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple spinner with only one element and different border styles.

```
.loader{
    border: 2px solid #CECECE; 
    border-top-color: #14B48C; 
    width: 40px; 
    height: 40px; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    animation: spin 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin{
    from{transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```